# Comparing 8 properties with 3 other properties and setting matches to NIL

Tags: objective-c

I have an object called brain

brain has 8 properties that contain an "Animal" object.

brain.animal1,
brain.animal2,
animal3,
...
brain.animal8

I then have three other properties called

brain.selectedAnimal1, brain.selectedAnimal2, brain.selectedAnimal3

What I would like to do is loop through all of the 8 animal properties... and if one of those animal properties matches up with selectedAnimal1 property, i want to set the animal property to nil.

I only want to set one animal property to nil (i.e. if two of the animal properties match the selectedAnimal1 property I only want the first one to be set to nil, not both)

Then I want to do the same loop but compare with selectedAnimal2 and selectedAnimal3 properties and set animal properties to nil if they match with a selectedAnimal.

Can anyone help with this?   I'm just not quite good enough yet with objective-c to get this to work without writing about 50 lines of code

So to recap...  I start with 8 animal properties and would like to end with 5 animal properties (3 being set to nil)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems very non-flexible and non-extendible to have animal1, animal2, ... and selectedAnimal1, selectedAnimal2, ...

You should really look into using collections (NSMutableArray or NSMutableSet), say animals and selectedAnimals, then you can loop through you animal objects using fast enumeration:

```
for (Animal* animal in animals) {
    for (Animal* selectedAnimal in selectedAnimals) {
        /* Do checks */
    }
}
```

If you find an animal which is in both you can remove it from animals. Careful not to change a mutable array while enumerating it, you'll get crashes. I think you should use NSMutableSet (which have union, minus operators and so on, making it easy to subtract common elements from one set).